# How do I use Sitecore.Data.Serialization.Manager.LoadItem(path,LoadOptions) to restore a item to Sitecore?

Tags: wcf, serialization, sitecore

I am trying to use the sitecore API to serialize and restore sitecore items.  I have created a WCF app to retrieve an Item name given a ID or sitecore path (/sitecore/content/home), retrieve a list of the names of the items children give an id or path.  I can also Serialize the content tree.

```
    public void BackupItemTree(string id)
    {
        Database db = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
        Item itm = db.GetItem(id);

        Sitecore.Data.Serialization.Manager.DumpTree(itm);
    }
```

The above code works great.  After running it can see that the content tree has been serialized.

However when I try to restore the serialized items useing the following:

```
    public void RestoreItemTree(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
            {
                Database db = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
                Data.Serialization.LoadOptions opt = new Data.Serialization.LoadOptions(db);
                opt.ForceUpdate = true;

                Sitecore.Data.Serialization.Manager.LoadItem(path, opt);
                //Sitecore.Data.Serialization.Manager.LoadTree(path, opt);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

With this code I get no errors.  It runs, but if I check SiteCore it didn't do anything.  I have tested using the Office Core example.  The path I sent in, which might be the issue is:

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitecoretest\Data\serialization\master\sitecore\content\Home\Standard-Items\Teasers\Our-Clients.item

and

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitecorebfahnestockinet\Data\serialization\master\sitecore\content\Home\Standard-Items\Teasers\Our-Clients

Neither seems to do anything.  I changed the teaser title of the item and am trying to restore to before the but every time the change is still present.

Any help would be appreciated as the SiteCore documentation is very limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the correct `LoadOptions` for forcing an overwrite (aka Revert).

I suspect that the path you are using for the `.item` file wrong. I would suggest modifying your method to take a path to a Sitecore item. Using that path, you should leverage other serialization APIs to determine where the file should be.

```
public void RestoreItemTree(string itemPath)
{
    Sitecore.Data.Database db = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
    Sitecore.Data.Serialization.ItemReference itemReference = new Sitecore.Data.Serialization.ItemReference(db.Name, itemPath);
    string path = Sitecore.Data.Serialization.PathUtils.GetFilePath(itemReference.ToString());

    Sitecore.Data.Serialization.LoadOptions opt = new Sitecore.Data.Serialization.LoadOptions(db);
    opt.ForceUpdate = true;

    using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
    {
        Sitecore.Data.Serialization.Manager.LoadItem(path, opt);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used the information from both post, but still no progress.  Ultimately using the ItemReference object ends up giving me the same: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitecoretest\Data\serialization\master\sitecore\content\Home\Standard-Items\Teasers\Our-Clients.item path that I was using before.  However I still see no changes within SiteCore and still no errors.  So I have cleaner code, but no solution yet.

Comment: I tested the function, as provided, and was able to revert an item. steps: 1. serialize you /sitecore/content/home item. 2. change a field on that item. 3. call that method with the "/sitecore/content/home" path.

Comment: You may need to clear the caches in order to see your changes. Check `/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx`.

Comment: Well I stand corrected.  I just tried again.  I wanted to test the cache idea, and today it is working as planned.  I have no idea why it wasn't working before, but thank you again for your help everyone...

Answer (score 2):

You can always check how the Sitecore code works using Reflector, the following method is called when you click "Revert Item" in back-end:

```
protected virtual Item LoadItem(Item item, LoadOptions options)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(item, "item");
    return Manager.LoadItem(PathUtils.GetFilePath(new ItemReference(item).ToString()), options);
}
```

In LoadOptions you can specify whether you want to overwrite ("Revert Item") or just update ("Update Item")  it.

See **Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.Serialization.LoadItemCommand** for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to work out, but you have to remove .item when restoring the tree

try this

```
    public void RestoreItemTree(string itemPath)
    {
        var db = Factory.GetDatabase("master");
        var itemReference = new ItemReference(db.Name, itemPath);
        var path = PathUtils.GetFilePath(itemReference.ToString());

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            throw new Exception("File not found " + path);
        }

        var opt = new LoadOptions(db);
        opt.ForceUpdate = true;

        using (new SecurityDisabler())
        {
            Manager.LoadItem(path, opt);
            Manager.LoadTree(path.Replace(".item", ""), opt);
        }
    }
```